# Unable to update the form object which is a part of Arraylist through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

I need to update an attribute in `formBean` which is part of `ArrayList` in the `formBean` when user checks or unchecks a checkBox.
The value of the attribute is by default set to `"on"` in the `formBean` before the page loads.
When user unchecks I am trying to make the value as `"off"`.
I am able to see the value changed to `"off"` using firebug debugger, but in submit the value of the form object is remaining `"on"` always.

My JSP code is below. Please let me know if I am setting the value in a wrong way.

Struts application

Display Logic in JSP:

```
    <input type="checkbox"
           name="importedFiles[<c:out value='${stts.count - 1}'/>].importEnabled"
           id="importedFiles[<c:out value='${stts.count - 1}'/>].importEnabled"
           onClick="replicateCheckbothis, <c:out value='${stts.count - 1}'/> )"
           <c:if test="${importedFiles.importEnabled != null}">checked</c:if> />
```

We are trying to change the value of `importEnabled` which is part of arrayList `importedFiles` in `maintainDownloadForm` during submit via JS.
Please find below the logic used:

```
function checkSelectedAndImport()
{
    var anyClicked = "none";

    for(var i = 0; i < <c:out value='${maintainDownloadForm.importedFileLength}' />; i++)
    {
        var element = document.getElementById("importedFiles[" + i + "].importEnabled");

        if(element != null)
        {
            if(element.checked)
            {
                anyClicked = "true";
                element.setAttribute('value', 'on'); alert('Selected--->'+element.getAttribute('value'));
            }
            else
            {
                element.setAttribute('value', 'off');
                alert('Not Selected--->'+document.getElementById("importedFiles[" + i + "].importEnabled").value);

            }
        }
    }

    if(anyClicked != "none")
    {
        submitDGForm(getVMWareForm(),'saveImport');
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No rows have been selected for import. Please select data to import. To cancel the import, click on cancel.");
    }
}
```

In the above logic we are able to go into `else` loop when user unchecks and print the `alert` as expected but the same is not getting updated with the form attribute `importEnabled` as it is always remaining `"on"` as it was the case before the page loaded.

Please let me know if there is any problem with the coding logic and also a fix for the same as it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think you can't. The solution I use is to keep an array of Strings (String[]) in the form and use javascript to add (orremove) some hidden inputs to the HTML DOM all with the ame of the Form string array. Those hidden inputs has a value that allows me to uniquely identify which chekboxes are selected by the user.